# View source of NumberFormatter class

Tags: php

I'm using the `NumberFormatter` class, and I want to see how the `formatCurrency` function is defined. I wasn't able to find the source for this online, or on my machine. Is there a standard place where PHP libraries are installed? Or is there some function that tells me the source of a class, like `get_source_file(NumberFormatter)`?

Comment: This should help: http://lxr.php.net/ or github: https://github.com/php/php-src

Comment: Ok, I found it here: http://lxr.php.net/xref/PECL/intl/formatter/formatter_format.c#137. @Rizier123 thanks for the tip! If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Downvoters: I hope this solution was incredibly obvious to you. As a PHP newbie it took me some digging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the source code for something you can use: http://lxr.php.net/ or the github page: https://github.com/php/php-src

Also you have to know that there are 2 main folders:

- [ext](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/) (Here you will find functions like: `strpos()`, `mysql_connect()`, ...)
- [Zend](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/) (Here you will find the engine and stuff about variables or `strlen()`, ...)

So you have to know if your search for a [function](http://php.net/manual/en/funcref.php) and use `"PHP_FUNCTION(strpos)"` to search for it or if you search for a [language construct](http://php.net/manual/en/langref.php) and use `"ZEND_FUNCTION(strlen)"`.

And don't forget, that `*.h` are header files and `*.c` holds the actual source code.